# CSS - Padding on the left side of a span that wraps around

Tags: html, css, padding

I have this simple html mockup:

```
<div class="grey wrap-text">
    <div id="content">
      <span contenteditable="true">
        <span class="bg">this is some text that that wraps around when there is too much text</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It produces this result:

[image]

CSS:

```
.bg {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding: 30px 20px 30px 30px;
}

.wrap-text {
  color: white;
  line-height: 130px;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 60px;
  padding: 0px 100px 0px 600px;
}
```

Ofc, this behaviour is not a bug or anything, it simply wraps around without adding any left padding on the next line.

But is there a way I can have the same padding on the left of the 'is' as before the 'this' whenever the text in the span wraps around?

Alternatively, how could one can the mockup to achieve this effect?

Thanks!

Comment: Provide some css code. Please.

Comment: okay, I added the class.

Comment: @Rechunk is this the complete css as compared to the attached image..?

Comment: @Bhuwan I only changed the font-size and family additionally. The red lines were added in paint to illustrate my question :)

Comment: @Rechunk make a snippet with your code...you will see...

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a `span` tag instead of a `p`? Spans are inline elements which can cause weird stuff to happen with padding.

Comment: @Bhuwan I added the additional css :)

Comment: @lexiexiexi well, I wanted to keep the text inline :)

Comment: What you really want, is [`box-decoration-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break) - but if you need to support MS browsers as well, then go with the box-shadow workaround from Zoilo's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the padding on the `wrap-text` class, it should remove the wonky spacing caused by the spans and too much padding.

You can force this (although its a little hacky) using a box-shadow to add space on the left and right of the lines instead of left and right padding. Here's a great article from [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/) about box-shadows.

```css
.bg {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding: 30px 0;
  box-shadow: 20px 0 0 black, -20px 0 0 black;
}

.wrap-text {
  color: white;
  line-height: 130px;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 60px;
/*   padding: 0px 100px 0px 600px;
   */}
```

```html
<div class="grey wrap-text">
    <div id="content">
      <span contenteditable="true">
        <span class="bg">this is some text that that wraps around when there is too much text</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: actually, it's the same as before.

Comment: I think I'm confused on what you are trying to create.  I get that making the text inline-block would the bg on the entire box, so are you just trying to get more space on the left and right side of the text?

Comment: I'm trying to get the padding on the left side of text on the new line which wrapped around (have a look at the red lines in the image I posted). But I guess that's quite hard with raw html and css.

Comment: I think you can use a box shadow to achieve this and just remove the padding on the left and right. Updating answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [box shadow method](https://codepen.io/fabien-d/pen/rHtal)

```css
.bg {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
  box-shadow: 30px 0 0 black, -30px 0 0 black;
  line-height: 100px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="grey">
    <div id="content" class='container'>
      <span contenteditable="true" class='container'>
        <span class="bg">this is some teeeeeeeeeeeext that wraps around when there is tooasdfasdfasd much text</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: it seems to only add a black box before and after the text starts on each line, but not actually behind it :/

Comment: awesome, it works If I use a combination of both your approach and mine!

Answer (score 0):

`display: inline-block` on `.bg` does the trick.

**[Problems with inline elements](http://maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/)**

`span` is an inline element. Properties like **padding**, **margin**, **width** and **height** to inline elements are only partially applied.

So, here, when you apply padding to `span`, which is an inline element, which means that the element is staying inline and not wrapping around. But in your image I can see that it got wrapped around because of unavailable space on the same line(inline). Hence as usual the padding is applied to the starting of the element and not below, because it is **inline** and **not a block**.

Hope this helps.

```css
.grey{
  background:#ddd;
}
.bg{
 padding-left:20px;
 display:inline-block;
  font-size:30px;
}
.abg{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grey">
    <div id="content" >
      <span contenteditable="true">
        <span class="bg">
          <span class='abg'>this is some text that that wraps around when there is too much text
          </span>
         </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And you can use `inline-block` on a `span`. No worries.

Comment: using inline-block would however add a background where there is no text, which is not my desired look in this case :/

Comment: updated the code. Check it. You can add another span inside it to achieve the background, you want.

Comment: @downvoter It would be helpful, if you explained the problem with my answer.